# PHP Simple Pagination

Tags: php, pagination

the below code is getting some values from DB by "select option form" , i recently added Pagination snip to limit the results, when i run the code it fetch 5 recorders as defined,but didn't show the remaining number of pages.
what im doing wrong here ?

```
<?php

$per_page = 5;
if (isset($_GET["page"])) {
    $page = $_GET["page"];
} else {
    $page = 1;
}

$start_from = ($page - 1) * $per_page;

if (!empty($_POST['form_val']) && isset($_POST['form_val'])) {
    $_POST['form_val'] = 0;

    $sql = "SELECT u.log_id , u.user_name, s.site, u.date ,u.comment , l.location, e.picture  FROM `pool` u, `location_all` l , `site_all` s JOIN db2.user e 
    where l.location_id = u.location and s.site_id = u.site and e.user_id = u.user_id";

    if (!empty($_POST['Location']) && isset($_POST['Location'])) {
        $sql = $sql . " AND location =" . $_POST['Location'];
    }
    $strtdate = $_POST['Sday'];
    $enddate  = $_POST['Eday'];
    if (!empty($_POST['Sday']) && isset($_POST['Sday']) && !empty($_POST['Eday']) && isset($_POST['Eday'])) {
        $sql = $sql . " AND date between '" . $strtdate . "' and '" . $enddate . "'";
    } elseif (!empty($_POST['Sday']) && isset($_POST['Sday'])) {
        $sql = $sql . " AND date>='" . $strtdate . "'";
    } elseif (!empty($_POST['Eday']) && isset($_POST['Eday'])) 
        $sql = $sql . " AND date<='" . $enddate . "'";
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['Site']) && isset($_POST['Site'])) {
        $sql = $sql . " AND u.site=" . $_POST['Site'];
    }

    $sql = $sql . " LIMIT $start_from, $per_page";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1) {
            $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            echo '<legend> ' . $rowcount . ' Records Found !!!</legend>';
            echo '<br><br>';
            echo "<table class='srchtable'>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Picture</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>User Name</th>
                    <th>country</th>
                    <th>Location</th>
                    <th>Site</th>
                    <th>Comment</th>
                    </tr>";
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td> <img src='" . $row['picture'] . "' alt='' style='width:70%; height:auto; border-radius: 50%;'> </td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['user_name'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['country'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['location'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['site'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['comment'] . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
            $total_pages = ceil($rowcount / $per_page);
            echo "<center><a href='?page=1'>" . 'First Page' . "</a> ";
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) {

                echo "<a href='?page=" . $i . "'>" . $i . "</a> ";

            }
            echo "<a href='?page=$total_pages'>" . 'Last Page' . "</a></center> ";
        } else {
            echo '<p>No Results Found !!!</p>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you start by fixing the indentation of your code? It will help (mostly you) understand the flow of your code.

Comment: See how you're calculating `$rowCount` there, you're calculating *total number of rows* but incorporating `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` values. Rather, you should have a simple query like this, `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE ...` without any `LIMIT` or `OFFSET` clause so that you could calculate total number of pages and display pagination links accordingly.

Comment: sorry for that, edited my Question

Comment: And since you have filtered your results based on `$_POST` data, you have to incorporate those in your pagination links as well, otherwise when you visit the next page you won't get the desired result.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul i fixed the row count calculation and now it returns number of pages remaining, put it behaves as you said in your next comment, can you explain it more please. appreciate if you use example.

Comment: @Mavia Which part you want me to explain more?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul how to incorporate `$_POST` data in the pagination links?

Comment: @Mavia I've given an answer below. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comments, for displaying pagination links:

- You're counting total number of rows but incorporating `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` clauses in your `SELECT` query, this won't give the correct number of row count. Your `SELECT` query should not contain this part, `... LIMIT $start_from, $per_page`.
- Since you're filtering the results based on several `$_POST` data, you should incorporate those conditions in your pagination links as well, otherwise when you visit a different page(through pagination link), you won't get the desired result, and that's because `$_POST` data will not be retained when you hop from page to page. **Better that you change the `method` of your `<form>` from `POST` to `GET`**, because in this way it'd be easier for you to catch and manipulate things when you hop from one page to another using pagination links.

So based on the above points, your code should be like this:

```
$per_page = 5;
if (isset($_GET["page"])) {
    $page = $_GET["page"];
} else {

    $page = 1;

}

$start_from = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
if (!empty($_GET['form_val']) && isset($_GET['form_val'])) {
    $_GET['form_val'] = 0;

    $sql = "SELECT u.log_id , u.user_name, s.site, u.date ,u.comment , l.location, e.picture  FROM `pool` u, `location_all` l , `site_all` s JOIN db2.user e 
    where l.location_id = u.location and s.site_id = u.site and e.user_id = u.user_id";

    if (!empty($_GET['Location']) && isset($_GET['Location'])) {

        $sql = $sql . " AND location =" . $_GET['Location'];

    }
    $strtdate = $_GET['Sday'];
    $enddate  = $_GET['Eday'];
    if (!empty($_GET['Sday']) && isset($_GET['Sday']) && !empty($_GET['Eday']) && isset($_GET['Eday'])) {
        $sql = $sql . " AND date between '" . $strtdate . "' and '" . $enddate . "'";
    } elseif (!empty($_GET['Sday']) && isset($_GET['Sday'])) {
        $sql = $sql . " AND date>='" . $strtdate . "'";
    } elseif (!empty($_GET['Eday']) && isset($_GET['Eday'])) {
        $sql = $sql . " AND date<='" . $enddate . "'";
    }
    if (!empty($_GET['Site']) && isset($_GET['Site'])) {
        $sql = $sql . " AND u.site=" . $_GET['Site'];
    }

    $data_query = $sql . " LIMIT $start_from, $per_page";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $data_query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1) {
        $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        echo '<legend> ' . $rowcount . ' Records Found !!!</legend>';
        echo '<br><br>';
        echo "<table class='srchtable'>
        <tr>
        <th>Picture</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>User Name</th>
        <th>country</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Site</th>
        <th>Comment</th>
        </tr>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td> <img src='" . $row['picture'] . "' alt='' style='width:70%; height:auto; border-radius: 50%;'> </td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['user_name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['country'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['location'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['site'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['comment'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";

        $query_result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $total_rows = mysqli_num_rows($query_result);
        $total_pages = ceil($total_rows / $per_page);

        parse_str($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"], $url_array);
        unset($url_array['page']);
        $url = http_build_query($url_array);
        ?>
            <center><a href="?page=1<?php echo isset($url) && !empty($url) ? "&" . $url : ""; ?>">First Page</a> 
        <?php
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) {
            ?>
            <a href="?page=<?php echo $i; echo isset($url) && !empty($url) ? "&" . $url : ""; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a> 
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        <a href="?page=<?php echo $total_pages; echo isset($url) && !empty($url) ? "&" . $url : ""; ?>">Last Page</a></center> 
        <?php
    } else {
        echo '<p>No Results Found !!!</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: i didn't know about `parse_str`, will read more about it. Thank you so much